# problem with rspec test, undefined method 'post'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

I am writing a spec to test the behavior of the mashup_controller when someone sends a query through a URL. I need to simulate the parameters contained in the URL, and i read that the post() method will do that, however when i get an error:

```
1) MashupController simulates query
     Failure/Error: post :create
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `post' for
#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x980bc50>
     # ./mashup_controller_rspec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.20199 seconds 1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./mashup_controller_rspec.rb:7 # MashupController simulates query
```

Here is my code:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'mashup_controller.rb'

describe MashupController do
    it "simulates query" do
        post :create    
    end
end
```

Sorry if I'm not making any sense. I am very new to rails and rspec. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show your directory structure. Also, what rails version are you using?  Does this mashup controller inherits from ApplicationController?

Comment: yeah, MashupController does inherit from ApplicationController. mashup_controller.rb is in another directory, but I added it to $LOAD_PATH, so i dont think that is the problem. Also, I am running Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.1, and rspec-rails 2.6.1. I am wondering if i just set something up wrong.

Answer (score 35):

If the spec file is not under `spec/controllers`, methods like `get` and `post` will not be automatically made available by `rspec-rails`.

You either need to tag your spec:

```
describe MyController, type: :controller do
  # ...
end
```

or include the module:

```
describe MyController do
  include RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup
  # ...
end
```

See [the relevant code in rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb).

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you have `gem spec-rails` in your Gemfile
2. Your `mashup_controller_rspec.rb` should be under `spec/controllers`

Comment: Your tests can also be under spec/requests and they will be able to post, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I used **gem rspec-rails** instead of gem spec-rails.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4, you can declare the type of the RSpec tests as `:request` and the spec file can be in any directory.

```
example: in spec/routes/users.rb
RSpec.describe 'UserRoutes', type: :request do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
describe MyController, type: :controller
...
end
```