# undefined method post for RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have this route:

```
post 'create', to: 'applications#create'
```

this controller:

```
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
  end
end
```

and this test:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe ApplicationsController do
  describe "routing" do
    it 'routes to #create' do
      post('/applications').should route_to('applications#create')
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my `spec_helper`:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :should
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :should
  end
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
end
```

Why when I run

```
rspec ./spec/routing
```

I get this error?

> Failure/Error: post('/applications').should route_to('applications#create') 
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `post' for RSpec

I tried changing the test using expect but with no luck. neither with a different class name.

What should I do to test my routes?

**UPDATE**

If I do this:

```
it "should return status 200" do
  post('/applications'), {}
  response.status.should be(200)
end
```

I get the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem with rspec test, undefined method 'post'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135377/problem-with-rspec-test-undefined-method-post)

Comment: Of course [that solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135377/problem-with-rspec-test-undefined-method-post) does not work for me

Comment: are you using the rspec-rails gem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000106db51f8>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296235/undefined-method-get-for-rspeccoreexamplegroupnested-10x00000106db51f)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it can help you but I had the same problem when passing to Rspec 3

According to https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure

we should enable that option to pass automatically metadata.

```
​# spec/rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Once this was added my specs passed.